# Google Chrome doesn't stay logged in to Google sites when using pinned tabs

Tags: google-chrome

Despite checking "stay logged in" or the like on Gmail or Docs, Chrome refuses to do so when I close and re-open it with Google sites pinned.  If they're **not pinned**, it **works fine**.

The "Clear cookies and other site and plug-in data when I close my browser" checkbox in the settings is *not* checked, and I don't have any cookie exceptions.  All **settings are defaults**.  Nor is the incognito mode being used.  This occurs on all my computers using Chrome.

I have deleted my cookies file (`%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cookies`) with no effect (other than losing the logins that ordinarly work fine).

Of note is that when I relaunch Chrome with Gmail pinned and it asks me to log in, doing so once will fail (does nothing; no errors), then it will work on the second attempt.  If I refresh the window before doing so, it will work on the first attempt.

Comment: and the specific cookie settings (don't keep/keep until browser shutdown/keep until expire)?

Comment: What about the third-party cookie setting?

Comment: @Synetechinc. all settings are defaults

Comment: Do you remain logged in across sessions in other browsers? If so, then it is definitely a Chrome problem. If not, then it is a Google account problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest ensure that you have not (recently and unintentionally) set Chrome to open a new instance of an Incongnito Window (which enables private browsing, thus not saving/storing any history or cookies, etc).

You can tell if you have an incognito window open by looking at the top left of the browser window - if you can see a shady-looking character bearing sunglasses and a hat, then your browser has gone incognito, my friend.

Comment: I am not in incognito mode for my main email session (I use out occasionally if I want to log into two gmail accounts at the same time, but this is outside that)

Comment: If you log in while in Incognito Mode, then navigate to another page, clear the cache, then navigate back, will it retain your login credentials for that session or prompt you to log in again?